# Junit not finding test class

Tags: java, junit

High I'm using junit for a class assignment and I keep getting a class not found error.

My test file looks like

IntegerArrayListTest.java

`

```
package howardedu.sycs363.spring15.lab5;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import howardedu.sycs363.spring15.lab3.IntegerArrayList;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IntegerArrayListTest {

    private IntegerArrayList defaultTestList;
    private IntegerArrayList singleParamTestList;

    /**
     * Print statement before all test.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("IntegerArrayList test class!!");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    }
}
```

The class I'm testing looks like

```
    package howardedu.sycs363.spring15.lab3;

public class IntegerArrayList {

    private int[] array; // Initial array
    private int size; // Size of the array
    private int end; // The last used index in the array

    public IntegerArrayList() {
        size = 25;
        end = 0;
        array = new int[size];
    }
```

Finally my file structure looks like:

```
Labs/
  Lab1
  Lab2
  Lab3
  Lab4
  Lab5
```

The commands I'm running are (from the Labs folder):

```
javac Lab3/howardedu/sycs363/spring15/lab3/IntegerArrayList.java Lab5/howardedu/sycs363/spring15/lab3/IntegerArrayListTest.java

java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Lab5/howardedu/sycs363/spring15/lab3/IntegerArrayListTest.java
```

Each time the junit output says it cannot find the IntegerArrayList class.

Any help is appreciated! I'm using Junit 4.12 on a linux system.

Comment: No we are not **High** !!!

Comment: How would you know that?

Comment: Try removing `.java` from the end of the last command.

Comment: run like this : java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Lab5/howardedu/sycs363/spring15/lab3/IntegerArrayListTest